# GROUP_CONCAT DISTINCT BY ID

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have 2 tables like this:
Table a:

```
ID  type
1    1
1    1
2    1

2    2
2    2
3    2
```

Table b:

```
ID  name
1    a
2    b
3    b
```

And expected result:

```
ID   type  name
1,2   1    a,b
2,3   2    b,b
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ID), a.type,
GROUP_CONCAT(SELECT name FROM b WHERE ID = a.ID)
FROM a GROUP BY a.type
```

but it's not working. I need name is GROUP_CONCAT and DISTINCT by ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution for my question:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.id), a.type, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM b
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ID, GROUP_CONCAT(a.ID)))
FROM a GROUP BY a.type
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.id), a.type, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.name)
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY a.type
```

Comment: It will return: ID ( (1,2), (2,3) ), type ( (1), (2) ), name ( (a,b), (b) )

Comment: the problem is that you need the `b, b` for type=2? what exactly is the meaning there? what you group by this column?

Comment: Yes, i need exactly b, b for type = 2. It's just an example of my problem. I have found a solution:
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.id), a.type, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM b WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ID, GROUP_CONCAT(a.ID))) FROM a GROUP BY a.type

Comment: Kindly post your solution as answer and mark it as best answer, which would be helpful for others